# Show that there is a polynomial $p(z)$ of degree at most $k$ such that $e^A = p(A)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, cayley-hamilton

> Let $\dim V<\infty$, and let $A\in L(V)$ be diagonalizable with distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_0, \lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Show that there is a polynomial $p(z)$ of degree at most $k$ such that $e^A = p(A)$.
>   (Hint: You may use any information you find about the Vandermonde matrix.)

This is for a Linear Algebra course and I'm not really sure how to start this. I've researched a little bit about the Vandermonde matrix, but for it being my first time seeing what it's about, I really don't know how to apply it to this problem.

It would be helpful if I could be directed in the right direction.

Comment: Do you know Cayley Hamilton theorem?

Comment: Do you know about the minimal polynomial?

Comment: @Mark I understand it to the extent that if $f(t)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $T$, the $f(T)=T_0$, or the zero transformation.

Comment: @copper.hat When we briefly touched on Jordan Canonical form, I think we talked about the minimal polynomial a little but not a lot. Some clarification on that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @VladdyT. one consequence of this is that if $f(T)$ is of degree $\ell$, then $\{I,T,T^2,\dots,T^{\ell-1}\}$ are a "sufficient basis" to write any $T^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  See if you can convince yourself of this, and see if you can see how this implies that $\sum_{i = 0}^\infty \frac{T^i}{i!} = \sum_{i = 0}^k a_iT^i$.

Comment: @VladdyT.: My comment was misleading, there is a simpler way: If $A$ is diagonal, then $e^A$ and $p(A)$ have a particularly simple form. Find an appropriate interpolating polynomial. That is, a polynomial of degree at most $k$ such that $p(\lambda_k) = e^{\lambda_k}$. Then $p(A) = e^A$.

Answer (score 2):

Find a polynomial $p$ of degree (at most) $k$ such that
$p(\lambda_i) = e^{\lambda_i}$, for $i=1,...,k$. This is where the Vandermonde matrix comes in.

If $\Lambda $ is diagonal with entries from $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k$, then
$p(\Lambda) = e^\Lambda$.

Note that if $V$ is invertible then for any polynomial $p$ we have $p(V^{-1} AV) = V^{-1} p(A) V$ and $e^{V^{-1} AV} = V^{-1} e^A V $.

Answer (score 0):

This is true more generally for any linear operator. Hint: the set of polynomials in $A$ is a linear subspace of $\operatorname{End}(V)$, hence closed (for the Euclidean topology).